# How versioned build_depend works?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Inspired by [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/101441/can-catkincmake-detect-the-version-of-a-dependency/), I'm trying to utilize `version_gte` defined in [REP-0127](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#various).
I created an empty package beginner_tutorials from [a tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/catkin/CreatingPackage), then placed in `package.xml`:

```
  <build_depend version_gte="1.10.3" version_lt="2.0">roscpp</build_depend>
```

where `$ rosversion roscpp` returns `1.10.2`, expecting build would fail. But `catkin_make`-ing (tried `install` too) doesn't not even yield warning and just passed normally. Am I missing something?

---

**Update**) Answer from @Dirk Thomas gong something in me, and it was actually the following that was missing.

```
catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136526/how-versioned-build_depend-works?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-03-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMake configure step **does** show a warning if you `find_package()` your build dependency and it does not satisfy the version specified in your package.xml file.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-13**:
Is there a way to let catkin return error instead of warning when the specified version dependency is not met?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-05-14**:
No, currently these are always only warnings. Since sometimes this is a scenario a developer might have setup locally it would be bad to escalate it into an error.